# Finding the inverse of a specific block matrix.

Tags: matrices, inverse, covariance

I have a problem where I have to calculate the inverse of a specific block matrix:
$$
    \begin{pmatrix}M^{-1}+B\Lambda^{-1}B^T & B\Lambda^{-1}A^T\\ A\Lambda^{-1} B^T & L^{-1} + A\Lambda^{-1}A^T \end{pmatrix}
$$
All three matrices $M$, $L$ and $\Lambda$ are symmetric but $A$ and $B$ are not square.

The general formula for computing the inverse of a block matrix requires either the inverse of $M^{-1} + B\Lambda^{-1}B^T$ or the inverse of $L^{-1} + A\Lambda^{-1}A^T$. Since that is the inverse of a sum of two matrices it can't be solved so I was hoping that there is another approach that might work.

If it might help, this is part of a larger covariance matrix:
$$
    \begin{pmatrix}\Lambda^{-1} & \Lambda^{-1}B^T & \Lambda^{-1}A^T \\ B\Lambda^{-1} & M^{-1}+B\Lambda^{-1}B^T & B\Lambda^{-1}A^T\\ A\Lambda^{-1} & A\Lambda^{-1} B^T & L^{-1} + A\Lambda^{-1}A^T \end{pmatrix}
$$

Comment: Can you try using the inverse of a block matrix along with the Sherman-Morrison-Woodbury identity? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Woodbury_matrix_identity

Comment: I did look in to that for inverting one of the two blocks on the diagonal, but the identity seems to always result in an expression that also contains something of the form $(\Lambda + B^TMB)$, which the again requires the same identity.

Comment: To invert the first matrix you cannot avoid the inverse of a sum of matrices because any Schur complement will have it. If your goal is to invert the full covariance matrix, you can use (8) from Henderson & Searle (1981, On Deriving the Inverse of a Sum of Matrices), and will yield $\begin{bmatrix} \Lambda + B^{T}MB+A^{T}LA & -\Lambda B^{T}M & -\Lambda A^{T} L \\ -MB \Lambda & M & 0 \\ -\Lambda AL & 0 & L \end{bmatrix}$